# SSIS - XML SOURCE does not reflect newly added input column

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

My ETL process consists of  consuming a large XML document into SQL Server 2014.
The XML Source object is linked to around 50 Oledb destination objects. The process uses an XSD and XLST (after stripping off multiple namespaces).

A new column is being added to the source file and as part of the development the following was done.

Alter the destination table to account for the new column.

I manually inserted the new field/datatype into the XSD. However, when trying to map the columns, the input column does not reflect the newly added one, in spite of refreshing it in the advance editor.

Is there a way to add the new column to the available input? I do not want to remap all the 50 objects.

Thank you.
SD

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Seriously though, sometimes I have had to restart VS to get new columns to show up in mapping.

Comment: I did not see a Restart option in VS, so  I stopped and restarted Integration services. No change.

Comment: Not the service, the box that is running Visual Studio.  Just closing Visual Studio and re-opening it should be sufficient.

Comment: yes ...that was done too. No change

Comment: Ok...my issue was resolved and this is what was done.                      Alter the destination object to reflect the new column.                    Manually add the new field with the data type to the XSD.                       Double click on the XML source.                                                      Select 'Columns'. Hit OK .                                                                     From the drop down box of the 'Output Name ' , select the recently modified table and map the missing External column to the  Output Column. Save the changes and you are good to go.